# inserting as variable in place of a column name that expects a int value in a select query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to reference a linked server data table, the way this table is set is each month is a column name plus the characters 'HC' appended to it. There is either a 1 or a 0 in this field. And each record is a person that has been put in as disabled or on military leave. Now for the month of Jan say Joe Bob was injured and off site. Well, he would have a 1 in the JANHC column, and he came back in February, so he has a 0 for that column. I have a date, and I depart the month to look a month behind in January since it is feb., so I assign 1 to a variable. I made a temp table with the column names shown in the code below I just match the month number to the month name and assign the name to a varchar variable, which I in turn use in a select statement but it breaks saying "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value JANHC to data type int. (does this for YEARHC as well but if I figure out how to fix one I can fix the other) is there some escape character that I can just put to use the value of the variable as the column name and still pass the expected int value in the query?

```
  DECLARE @DATE AS INT
  DECLARE @MonthColumn As VARCHAR(20)
  DECLARE @YearColumn As VARCHAR(20)

SET @DATE = DATEPART(M, GETDATE())
SET @DATE = @DATE-1 

create table #temp
(
    Month    integer,
    MonthName    VARCHAR(10)
)


INSERT into #temp(Month,MonthName)VALUES(1, 'JANHC')
INSERT into #temp(Month,MonthName)VALUES(2, 'FEBHC')
INSERT into #temp(Month,MonthName)VALUES(3, 'MARHC')
INSERT into #temp(Month,MonthName)VALUES(4, 'APRHC')
INSERT into #temp(Month,MonthName)VALUES(5, 'MAYHC')
INSERT into #temp(Month,MonthName)VALUES(6, 'JUNHC')
INSERT into #temp(Month,MonthName)VALUES(7, 'JULHC')
INSERT into #temp(Month,MonthName)VALUES(8, 'AUGHC')
INSERT into #temp(Month,MonthName)VALUES(9, 'SEPHC')
INSERT into #temp(Month,MonthName)VALUES(10,'OCTHC')
INSERT into #temp(Month,MonthName)VALUES(11,'NOVHC')
INSERT into #temp(Month,MonthName)VALUES(12,'DECHC')

SET @MonthColumn = (SELECT MonthName FROM #temp Where Month= @DATE)    --CONTAINS 'JANHC'
SET @YearColumn = 'YEARHC'
DROP TABLE #temp

PRINT @MonthColumn

--(SELECT * FROM [BLAH].[BLAH].[DATAPLACE].[NEVERLANDTABLE]WHERE YEARHC = 2017 AND JANHC = 1) 
(SELECT * FROM [BLAH].[BLAH].[DATAPLACE].[NEVERLANDTABLE]WHERE @YearColumn = 2017 AND @MonthColumn = 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great opportunity to use `UNPIVOT` since you know the column names and it would be much easier to deal with the data as rows. This expands your columns into rows, effectively. In the `UNPIVOT` statement here, `on_leave` is the name of the returned column that will hold the values from each column in the original table we've called `month`.

```
create table hr_leave (
    person varchar(100) not null,
    JANHC bit not null default 0,
    FEBHC bit not null default 0,
    MARHC bit not null default 0,
    APRHC bit not null default 0
)
go

insert into hr_leave values
('Mike',  1, 0, 1, 0),
('Evan',  1, 1, 1, 1),
('Marie', 0, 0, 0, 0);

SELECT h.person, u.month, u.on_leave
FROM hr_leave h
UNPIVOT (
    on_leave FOR month IN (JANHC, FEBHC, MARHC, APRHC)
) u;


person  month  on_leave
-------------------------
Mike    JANHC  True
Mike    FEBHC  False
Mike    MARHC  True
Mike    APRHC  False
Evan    JANHC  True
Evan    FEBHC  True
Evan    MARHC  True
Evan    APRHC  True
Marie   JANHC  False
Marie   FEBHC  False
Marie   MARHC  False
Marie   APRHC  False
```

From here it'd be easy to use a `CASE` statement to convert the month names to numbers and then you're dealing with some real easy to use normalised data!

If you really do want to select a specific column, you need to use dynamic SQL. Check out [sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) for how to do this. A big downside to this is you can't use it in a select query, view, or UDF. It can only be done in scripts and stored procedures.